# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.blockonomics.co/js/pay_button.js (“default-src”)

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Trying to use blockonomics to aceped payments on my next js site. I have added a meta tag -

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.blockonomics.co"/>
```

in my _document.tsx file -

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
         <Head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.blockonomics.co"/>

      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

But it still gets blocked. -

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.blockonomics.co/js/pay_button.js”. 
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). 
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.blockonomics.co/js/pay_button.js (“default-src”).
```

Any help is appreciated. This site is a tor site.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the site has another Content Security Policy set. Check the response headers for the page, and you'll likely find it. Adding another policy can only make it stricter, so you need to find the other policy/policies and modify/remove them.